# Plot sinewave on ZX axis

Tags: matlab, octave

I am trying to plot a sinewave with a bit of 3d perspective along the ZX axis instead of the XY axis.  I have so far been unable to get anything that works, and have been unable to locate any examples.  I have tried a few different things with plot3() but that has all resulted in either parallel lines (no longer a sinewave) or nothing.

To add clarity, I do not want to change the labels but rather have a 3-axis plot where a 2d sinewave is on the ZX axis.

Here is the closest thing I have (just found the rotate and view commands).  However the sine waves only fully render when looked at dead on, which makes one of the two invisible.  I would like to be able to view both, at an angle so you can see the relationship between them.

```
clf;
rotate3d on;
frequency = 5;
timeperiod = 1;
dcoffset = 0;
amplitude = 0.1;
t=0:0.00001:timeperiod;
out=dcoffset+amplitude*sin(2*pi*frequency*t);
plot(t,out, "linewidth", 3);
hold on;
out=dcoffset+amplitude*sin(2*pi*frequency*t);
ew=plot(t,out, "linewidth", 3);
rotate(ew,[1 0 0], 90);
view(3,[22 45 45]);
```

TIA

Answer (score 0):

Now that I know more search terms I found this.  It is effectively what I wanted to do.

https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/a/14352/33469